# How to modify 2 raster images to have the same resolution?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, imagery, erdas-imagine, resolution

I have data for 2 rasters images that have different resolutions:

1. `z` downloaded from trmm
2. An MSAVI2 output image.

For calculating the correlation between them, the data has to be in the same resolution. I have tried reproject in erdas but the result that I got was not `z` correct.

How can I do this? Or how to do this with the resample command in arcgis?

Answer (score 1):

ERDAS *should* be faster for image processing, but if you want to do it in ArcMap it's pretty straightforward. Since you are trying to get both images to the same resolution, you would specify the path to the other image for the cell_size parameter. Depending on what classification your images fall under will determine the best resampling method to use.

Consult the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009t000000) for a description of all this.

If you want to do this is in ERDAS, there is a tool (in 2011, it is located under Raster tab->Spatial->Resample Pixel Size) that I think is what you are looking for. From the help:

> The Resample dialog resamples raster image data to a specified pixel size. Unlike Reproject, this dialog does not transform or project data from one map projection to another.

Answer (score 0):

You should use globle mapper for resampling , this is very helpful.
Also You can use arcgis, try simply export data . during this change cell size.
Then you will find the same pixel value of both raster images.